# How to choose the right database for lyrics

Tags: database, firebase, react-native, sqlite

I am new in mobile app development and I am developing an application in React Native, which will contains the lyrics of songs. Now, I am in a situation where I am thinking about the best way to make database for it.

I would like the basic lyrics to be downloaded to the device with the app, but also that the user can add other songs that would only be visible to him. Which way is the best? I think, that all songs could be saved into some database (for example in device storage or SD-card). I think about SQLite or Firebase, but is this the right way?

Thank you for all your advice ;)

Comment: I know you're looking for advice; SO is not a good source for that. This forum is to help with existing code; post the code you're having difficulty with, include the troubleshooting and expected output and we'll try to help. The problem is that without knowing your entire use case, any answers would be opinion based and really just guesswork, sending you off in the wrong direction. For example, you mention 'downloading lyrics' downloading from where? Then you mention saving songs - again, saving songs... locally in the device? There are simply too many variables to cover here on SO.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. See [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for info.

Answer (score 0):

Whole solution seems like a good use case for Firebase/Firestore.

Firestore seems to integrate well with mobile apps. It's also managed so it's a simple way to run a database for a mobile app given you can provide the customer with direct access to the database without the need for a backend.

Comment: Thank you... so, can I store some basic lyrics in the database (Firebase/Firestore) and then the user can add their own, which will be unique only on his device?

Comment: Depends on the structure and how you design it all. It's a no-sql database that's great for having users contribute there own records and having many reads. You could have a list of songs for example by a user id and the user sees their own lyrics as separate from the rest in that way e.g. (if my custom lyrics exist for this song, use them, else use the default). If that's what you're kind of trying to accomplish?
Check out the firestore youtube series from Firebase, it's an awesome introduction to all the features and the data structure design.